# How to make TextBox rethink it's preferred height?

Tags: winforms

i'm constructing a `TextBox` at runtime:

```
edit = new TextBox();
this.Controls.Add(edit);
edit.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
```

Sometime later i set the location (`Location`, `Left`/`Top`) of the edit box:

```
edit.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
```

Problem is that *before* i adjust the text box's location its `Height` is **20 px**. e.g.:

```
edit.Height     20
```

But as soon as i change the `Location`, the text box's height changes to **13 px**, e.g.:

```
edit.Height     13
```

The problem, of course, is that my value of `newY` is based on the height of the text box. As soon as i adjust the text box's location it then shrinks itself - making my calculated value useless.

What i would like is a way to force a `TextBox` to rethink it's height:

**Before**

```
newX = (int)Math.Round(2*scaleFactor.Width);
newY = (containerHeight - edit.Height) / 2;
```

**After**

```
edit.RethinkAutoSize();
newX = (int)Math.Round(2*scaleFactor.Width);
newY = (containerHeight - edit.Height) / 2;
```

How can i tell a textbox to update it's internal sense of it's "proper" height?

Comment: Was 20 correct? I mean, maybe it should rethink (I love the word) its height earlier.

Comment: i stole the term from Borland's equivalent of the .NET Framework, which used `RethinkLines` as a method to update the visibility of a menu separator when nithing's below it. Later i stole it the same term for other such things, where ambient conditions have changed and the object-oriented nature of object wrappers becomes a hindrance, and we have to break encapsulation to make things work. Presumably 20 wasn't correct, since it decided it didn't like it anymore.

Comment: I've been rethinking... the only way I see is to (re)set the font of the TextBox.